# Unable to merge datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, data-preprocessing

I have scraped data from two different pharma websites. So, I have 2 datasets in hand:-

[image: First Dataset]

[image: Second Dataset]

Both datasets have a name column in common. What I am trying to achieve is combining these two datasets. My final objective is to get all the tables from the first dataset and product descriptions from the second dataset wherever the name is the same in both tables.

I tried using information from geeks for geeks:- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-types-of-joins-in-pandas/

and https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

but not getting the expected result.

Also, I tried it using the for loop but to no avail:-

```
new_df['Product_description']=''
for i in range(len(new_df['Name'])):
    for j in range(len(match_data['Name'])):
        if type(new_df['Name'][i]) != float:
            if new_df['Name'][i] == match_data['Name'][j].split(' ')[0].strip():
                new_df['Product_description'][i] = match_data['Product_Description'][j]
```

### I also tried:

[image: Merge Code and result]

but it's giving me 106 result which was from the older dataset and I need 251 results as in the new_df.
I want something like this but matched from the match_df data frame.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing here?

### Result with left join

[image]

Also, below are the values I am getting after finding the unique values sorted.

[image: Sorted unique values]

Comment: Can you create a couple simple examples with mock data?  Just script out a couple tables with ten or so rows and join them?  Then we can see both the details of table structure and how you're merging them in a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the size of the first dataframe constant, you need to use left join. If there are mismatched values, it will be set to null, but this will keep the size constant.

Also remember that the first parameter of the merge method is the dataframe whose size you want to keep constant when 'how' is 'left'.

Comment: Yes, using left I am getting the size but not the desired output. Hw ca I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure the name values match exactly? Because second table has alternative names in paranthesis and that is a complete string. I don't have any direct comparison examples above but just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep new_df length, I would suggest to use `how='left'` argument in

```
pd.merge(new_df, match_data, on="Name", how="left")
```

So it will do a left join on new_df.

Based in the screenshots you shared, I would double-check there are names in common in both dataframes "Name" column

Comment: I tried this but it's not giving the correct output. I am getting it using the right but with the wrong column.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these?

```
desc_df1 = pd.merge(new_df, match_data, on='Name', how='inner')
desc_df1 = pd.merge(new_df, match_data, on='Name', how='left')
```

After trying these options let us now, because I could not able to understand from your data preview. Can you sort Name.value_counts() ascending and check is there any dublicates in both df's ?.If so this is why you got this problem

Comment: Yes, I tried both of them but still to no avail. Also, I have edited my question with the unique value of both datasets.